# GLSL fragment shader syntax error

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

the following simple fragment shader code fails, leaving me with an uninformative message in the log:
`ERROR: 0:1: 'gl_Color' : syntax error syntax error`

```
void main()
{
  vec4 myOutputColor(gl_Color);
  gl_FragColor = myOutputColor;
}
```

while the following one works:

```
void main()
{
  glFragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

This boggles my mind, as in [Lighthouse3D's tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/index.php?color) gl_Color is said to be a vec4. Why can't I assign it to another vec4?

Comment: Is the error message really authentic? Is it normal/expected for it to miss the column/line number, and include the "syntax error" text twice?

Comment: yes, the error message is authentic (I have omitted an underscore in the examples, hence the edit). I don't really know what's normal/expected with GLSL info logs; in most of the cases the location of the error wasn't displayed, just the problematic variable / function name. (The environment is OS X, xcode, OpenGL 2.0 with an ATI driver v1.5)

Comment: *bump*bump* Hey slacker! Did it work? ;)

Comment: sure did. I was hesitant whose answer shall I accept because both work just fine, but I ended up with yours for brevity / human-readability.

Comment: The second answer is just as correct really, but there isn't any need to use the vec4() constructor, since both are of the same type. If you had lets say a (r,g,b,w) tuple you could write:

vec4 myOutputColor = vec4(r, g, b, w);

Comment: You have to provide explicit type conversions – no casting in GLSL.
Only int to float implicit conversions are allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try normal assignment. Like this:

```
void main()
{
  vec4 myOutputColor = gl_Color;
  gl_FragColor = myOutputColor;
}
```

Edit:

The second answer is just as correct really, but there isn't any need to use the vec4() constructor, since both are of the same type. If you had lets say a (r,g,b,w) tuple you could write:

```
vec4 myOutputColor = vec4(r, g, b, w);
```

or

```
// assuming myRgbColor is a vec3
vec4 myOutputColor = vec4(myRgbColor, w);
```

etc

Answer (score 4):

Aparrently you should use slightly different syntax

(see [OpenGL Shading Language Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) )

```
vec4 myOutputColor = vec4(gl_Color);
gl_FragColor = myOutputColor;
```

this unlike your sample compiles fine on my mashine (Windows, Nvidia card)